# Placing maximum int value on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a small table that keeps track of the number of pictures that are saved in a particular folder. I was wondering is there anything in SQL that would allow me to put a maximum numerical limit? I only want a particular column named **photocount** to have a maximum value of 4,000.
The **photocount** is increased by +1 each time a new photo is uploaded and I want to allow it to hold a maximum value of 4,000 and I already have the code to create a new folder, once it reaches 4,000 . This is how I have my table set up thus far...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[photocheck]
(
    [photocheckId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [directoryname] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [photocount] INT NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: a constraint.....but it would be a rather unusual design...

Comment: Why 4000? Why not 3999 or 4001? I'd understand the power of 2, e.g. 4096.

Comment: 4000 is the maximum amount of pictures allowed per folder while still being able to browse the picture folder.

Comment: @user1591668, are there any gaps in the photocheckId range? In other words 4000 would be the last number allowed in photocheckId column or is there a possibility that some numbers are skipped in photocheckId during the incrementing mechanism and only count(photocheckId) should be less than 4000 and not the actual numbers.

Comment: Yes the photocheckID has some gaps because now with MSSQL 2012 the new ID fields can skip by increments of 1,000. I also have created Server c# code to check on the value of Photocount so that it will not go over 4,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my understanding once a folder is filled with `4000` photos. You switch to a new folder and reset the photo count to 0. You can add a constraint to table structure to avoid the value above 4000. But, to avoid unwanted exception better check the new photo count value on new insertion.

Here the not needed constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE #photocheck
(
[photocheckId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
[directoryname] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[photocount] INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT CheckRegNumber  CHECK (photocheckId <= 4000)
)
```

To make sense:
    while insertion use if condition.

> ```
> IF(@photocount <= 4000)
> BEGIN
>    --Insert new row.
> END
> ELSE
>   --Warn with count exceeds 4000.
> BEGIN 
> END
> ```